# Curl string append problems, curl_formadd C++ reads variable with extra character but works just fine directly CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "key" [?]

Tags: c++, string, libcurl

Adding a string in a CURL post variables

```
curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
               CURLFORM_END);
```

This up there works just fine the POST key comes with "submit" in the page content.

but this:

```
string post = "submit";
 curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, &post,
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
               CURLFORM_END);
```

but this up here the page content in result comes with a extra weird character like "◘ER☺submit" instead of clean "submit"

what am I missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `std::string::c_str()`:

```
string post = "submit";
curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, post.c_str(),
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
             CURLFORM_END);
```

By using `&post`, you are extracting the address of the `std::string`, which is a completely different data type than a `const char*` you used when simply using the quoted string. `std::string::c_str`, on the other hand, returns the `const char *` that actually stores the string.

**EDIT**: regarding your concatenation question, `std::string` can be concatenated. Therefore:

```
std::string data = "submit";
data += " foo"; //data will be "submit foo";
std::string data2 = data + " yey"; //data2 will be "submit foo yey";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It works perfectly and I get what you said. It is a silly mistake, I'm a beginner in C++ :)

Comment: Hey another silly question, what do I do to append a value at it like (I'm using + as a concatenating char): CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send" + "hello" or CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send" + variable, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can, it says I have to wait 3 minutes to accept an answer ^_^